# What does the error code "VR-0002" mean when creating a scratch org?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

Been getting this error when creating a scratch org:

> The request to create a scratch org failed with error code: VR-0002.

The definition file is quite simple, so I don't know what might be causing it. I saw that the error VR-0003 might be related to the release version so I've added the `"release": "previous"` part in my definition file, but with no success.

File:

```json
{
  "orgName": "TheApp",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features": [
    "EnableSetPasswordInApi"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  },
  "language": "en_US",
  "country": "US",
  "release": "previous"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is related to [incident #10793](https://status.salesforce.com/incidents/10793):

> The Salesforce Technology team will begin deploying the Spring ‘23 release at 06:00 UTC on February 14, 2023 / 10:00 pm PT on February 13, 2023. It is expected that the release will be deployed to all instances by the start of business (PT) on February 14, 2023. Until the release is deployed, customers will be unable to create or refresh Sandboxes, create new Scratch Orgs, deploy metadata from their existing Sandboxes to their Production Orgs using Change Sets, or create new second-generation Managed and Unlocked Package versions.

It seems to be [possible to create preview orgs though](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000003BIYGQA4&title=spring-23-north-american-sandbox-feature-disruption), by changing the "release" parameter to "preview":

> Scratch Org Error
> Customers can create Scratch Orgs on the Spring ‘23 Salesforce release by specifying “release”: “preview” in their Scratch Org configuration file. With this workaround, customers must use version 56.0 of the Metadata API with their Scratch Orgs to deploy and retrieve metadata that is compatible with their Production (Dev Hub) Org version. When using the CLI, the Metadata API version can be updated by either setting the SFDX_API_VERSION=56.0 environment variable or by executing the sfdx config:set apiVersion=56.0 --global command. Once the Production (Dev Hub) Org has upgraded to Spring ‘23, the release tag must be removed from the configuration file in order to create Scratch Orgs.